# Instagram API getting error on UTF-8 characters (tested on /tags/{TAGNAME}/media/recent)

Tags: api, utf-8, instagram

Shamelessly stolen from this ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/tRfU444ZyhU ) thread as I have the exact same issue and hoping for better responses here.

Long story short, a few hours ago this was working, now it isn't.

The test platform can be found at both from my website and https://apigee.com/console/instagram

Sending https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/türkiye/media/recent    (careful with the "ü")

```
result:   {
  "meta":  {
    "error_type": "OAuthParameterException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": ""client_id" or "access_token" URL parameter missing. This OAuth request requires either a "client_id" or "access_token" URL parameter."
  }
}
```

Sending https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/turkiye/media/recent  (now with "u")

```
result:   {

  "pagination":  {},
  "meta":  {},
  "data":  [
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {},.. .. .. ... and so on
```

Sending  https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/türkiye/media/recent?client_id=7176aa6ef2fd47fd9cb373a5354bd30f ("ü" again and this time manually attached client_id)

```
result:    {

  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  {
    "media_count": 1471127,
    "name": "t"
  }
}
```

This time I'm getting the name as "t". It seems the query is broken just before the "ü" letter which is UTF-8 (Turkish if needed).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Instagram-side. There's an [open discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/tRfU444ZyhU) on Instagram Developers Google group. Although, from what I've seen in my application, the bug now resolve.